# SQL Server Insert table into same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create some **test data** for the project i am working on. At the moment I have about `64000` records in my table but I need more. My question is can i copy all these rows and insert them again ?

I have tried:

```
Select * INTO dbo.Calls from dbo.Calls
```

Comment: Title says SQL Server. Code sample seems to be SQL Server. Tags say mysql. Could you tidy this up please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Primary keys must contain unique value and cannot contain NULL values. so use following queries if your table don't have primary key.

for all columns use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Calls SELECT * fROM  dbo.Calls
```

for selected columns use:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.Calls (<column name list>) SELECT  <column name list> FROM dbo.Calls
```

Answer (score 1):

use this query incase you **don't** have `primary key` in it

```
insert into table_name
select * from table_name
```

if you have `primary key` then use this

```
insert into table_name (col2,col3)
select col2,col3 from table_name
```

Comment: If they have a primary key, then they cannot (by definition) duplicate the rows. I think what you were aiming for was "an identity column" (which, again, precludes exactly duplicating the rows). Identity columns and primary keys are two separate concepts, and shouldn't be taken to be synonyms.